# IOS data notifications with FCM

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM (firebase cloud messaging) to send "custom" data notifications to an IOS app. From what I understand, we use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your app's behalf. And we use data messages when you just want to process the messages only in your app. It's by design.

Problem I am facing is that that Device/InstandID token is unique to installed app and not the user logged in the app. So to solve this, I am sending intended user tag in the data so it becomes a data message. Since the app handles the data notifications, the didReceiveRemoteNotification() callback is only fired when the app is opened and the notification is only shown than and not instantly when it's sent.

My question is that can I send a custom data notification message and make it appear instantly even when the app is closed.

This is the payload I am sending to FCM:

```
{
    registeration_ids : [<id_1>, <id_2>],
    data : {
        title   : message_title,
        body    : message_body, 
        intended_user : message_user
    }
}
```

In android `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived()` is invoked even if the app is in the background but in ios `didReceiveRemoteNotification()` is only invoked when the application is launched so no background messages will appear if you send a data message.

Comment: Are you sending the message from the API or through the Firebase console? All messages from the Firebase console are notification messages even those with custom data. If you are sending from the API could you include your proposed request it will clear up what you are trying.

Comment: I am sending the message through API. Please see updated version of the question for the Payload data.

Comment: FCM data messages will not be received when your application is in the background on iOS. This is because you must (should) disconnect from FCM when your application is in the background. You should try sending a notification message, which goes through APNs which will work in the background also with content_available field set so your app is able to handle the callback in the background.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From what I understand so far, there is no way of solving this issue properly on the ios side. It works perfectly on the android side because the application is awoken in all states (foreground, background & closed).

You have two kinds of messages you can send:

A **notification-message** which is displayed and handled by the operating system directly.

A **data-message** which is handled by the application.

If you add a custom tag, it now becomes a data-message and would have to be handled by the application. You can add a `content_available` tag in data-message to let the application know about the message but the problem is that the data-message is only delivered to the application in ios if the application is in the foregrounded (opened) or in the background (minimised). The data-message will not be delivered to the application if the user has "force-closed" the application (even with the background notifications enabled).

Solution is to handle the intended user on the server side and solve the multiple-users to one-device-token problem by maintaining the a one to one device-token to user relationship.

Comment: So you're saying that if I want to process the data sent from FCM on the device in order to generate a message, I have no choice but to wait for the app to be opened?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy  Only if the app is not running.

Comment: @Dylanthepigguy You can also send a notification which shows in the system tray and can include a link to activate the app.

Comment: Also mentioned in Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application#discussion:~:text=However%2C%20the%20system%20does%20not%20automatically%20launch%20your%20app%20if%20the%20user%20has%20force%2Dquit%20it.)

Answer (score 26):

Poor Documentation from Firebase!

For iOS, Data messages can't be received when app is killed. But this is not mentioned anywhere in their documentation. So I contacted Firebase and this is what they said:

> Though there is a content_available parameter, data messages cannot be received when the app is killed. It can only be received on background and in foreground. If you wish to receive data messages when the app is killed, you need to send it along a display messages.

So its better to use APNS for ios rather if you ever thought of using same payload for android and Ios in FCM.

Comment: Are you serious ?

Comment: yes pretty much. This was the reply from Firebase when I contacted them. I'm not sure if they have updated the sdk to include these changes. Please refer their latest documentation for more info.

Comment: Have you used APNS then?

Comment: Can we awake the killed IOS app with APNS like we can with Android>

Comment: APNS is recommended for ios notification. yes it will show the notification even if the app is killed

Comment: I am using react-native. How to implement that in IOS. Any guidance?

Comment: you can try https://hackernoon.com/complete-guide-receive-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-app-38b1ec5b1b15

Answer (score 18):

Try to set content_available to true.

> **From the fcm documentation :**
>
> Note: If you want to send messages consisting of only custom key-values to an iOS device when the app is in the background, set custom key-value pairs in the data key and set content_available to true.

```
{
    registeration_ids : [<id_1>, <id_2>],
    content_available: true,

    data : {
        title   : message_title,
        body    : message_body, 
        intended_user : message_user
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but there is no way to solving this on the application side. `content_available` only works if the application is in the background or the foreground. If the application is "force-closed" by the user, there is no way a data-message can go through to the application (only ios is effected by this, it works fine on android). Solution is to use notification message, where the displaying of the message is handled by the operating system instead of the application. We sort out the intended user stuff by maintaining a 1-to-1 mapping of device token to user on the server side.

Answer (score 17):

I noticed that notification will arrive when app is force-closed in case that notification priority is set to high.

```
{  "notification": {
    "body" : "This week’s edition is now available.",
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "text": "5 to 1",
    "content_available": 1
  },
  "data" : {
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  },
  "to" : "fqUk65A1kTE:APA91bG5...", // or set topic like "/topics/test"
  "priority" : "high"
}
```

For iOS client apps, normal and high priority are analogous to APNs priority levels 5 and 10.

From the iOS documentation it is possible that notification with default priority are not delivered.

> apns-priority: The priority of the notification. Specify one of the following values:
>
> 10–Send the push message immediately. Notifications with this priority
>   must trigger an alert, sound, or badge on the target device. It is an
>   error to use this priority for a push notification that contains only
>   the content-available key.
>
> 5—Send the push message at a time that
>   takes into account power considerations for the device. Notifications
>   with this priority might be grouped and delivered in bursts. They are
>   throttled, and in some cases are not delivered. If you omit this
>   header, the APNs server sets the priority to 10.

**Update 1:**

The above notification is sent through FCM api and it was received while app was killed.
After I tap the notification on device this is what appears in device log after the app has started:

```
...didReceiveRemoteNotification: [gcm.message_id: 0:1468481012881485%e1d60a46e1d60a46, volume: 3.21.15, aps: {
        alert =     {
            body = "This week\U2019s edition is now available.";
            title = "Portugal vs. Denmark";
        };
    }, contents: http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772][;
```

Notice that data part is also contained in received message.

**Update 2:**

Multiple users on single device or one user with many devices.

On your server side you must assure that one unique fcm_id can be assigned only to one user. This means that one device is assigned to one user, so only one user will be notified per device.

Also, one user can have multiple fcm_ids, so it means user can have more devices and be signed in.

When the user_2 log in to same device of user_1, fcm_id must be detached from the user_1 and attached to user_2. Within this way, only currently logged in user will receive the message.

Comment: I have set the priority to high. Problem is the data part will not be processed if the app is removed from background.

Comment: that is correct, but I think you do not understand what I am trying to solve. If I add a intended user tag in data, that means no instant notification if the app is closed. It has to be opened by the user to read the intended user tag and then display the notification. Only way to INSTANTLY deliver a notification where multiple users logged in the same device is by keeping a record of current user to device token on the server side.

Comment: The notification that is displayed does not include the intended user tag. Notification is displayed first and on click the intended user data is then sent to app. With your approach, The previous users who logged into device, will have their messages shared with the current user. I want to only display the notification if the currently logged in user is the intended user and at the same time deliver the message INSTANTLY. Only way to do this is map 1 user to 1 device token and invalidating old relationships on the server side.

Comment: if it was not clear on my part, that is exactly what I am saying below in my answer. But I'll accept your answer as it has more relevant detail.

Comment: @yoyo are you receiving the msg (when the app is killed) if  "priority" : "high" in the server side? I am just curious to know because we are facing the same issue for ios

Comment: After wasting a few hours trying to understand why the notifications on the iOS device are delivered randomly, setting the ```"priority" : "high"``` saved me finally. Thanks :)

Comment: @Subho just read your message. Yes, that was also the very same problem we had and setting the priority to high solved it.

Comment: You can't sent data message to the ios if the ios device app is killed. "priority" : "high" can't solve the data message problem in case of ios @MyFlashLab
According to firebase you can only send notification message when the app is killed for ios

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy receiving a wrong APS dictionary x_x now everything it's working yeah

Comment: Did you guys enable the "Push notification" capabilities in xcode as well when trying this? I don't receive the data nor the notification attributes when the payload is sent to the device.

Answer (score 3):

The key problem is sending message to specific user group for the latest identity logged in.

Actually you can use topic messaging to solve the problem. Suppose you have 3 user tags/groups A,B and C. When FCM is initialized, register to 1 topic for All users to ensure that you can send a message to all user tags.

For specific user tags, subscribe to A if user signed in as A. After the user signed out and signed in as B, check if the user has subscribed to A/C or not. If yes, unsubscribe from A/C and then subscribe to B. This can then avoid handling tags involved in data section.