# Can you receive a FCM notification after user force quits your ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I understand that no background operation can be done after an app is forced quit on ios. But can the app still receive an FCM/GCM message and show a notification right after it was forced quit?

Comment: AFAIK, if you force quit an app this will make you unable to receive a notification. You can check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166203/ios-data-notifications-with-fcm) regarding IOS data notifications with FCM. In the discussion, if the application is "force-closed" by the user, there is no way a data-message can go through to the application (only ios is effected by this, it works fine on android). Solution is to use notification message, where the displaying of the message is handled by the operating system instead of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was Yes.

With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:

1) Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These will be delivered even if the app was just forced quit.
2) Data messages, which are handled by the client app. These will be handled in the background and therefore if an app was forced quit on iOS, these won't be delivered to the app.