# How to make a GCM / FCM notification-type message non-collapsible

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) support two types of push messages: "notification" messages and "data" messages. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages), notification messages are collapsible by default, while data messages are non-collapsible by default.

In order to make a data message collapsible, you need to specifiy a `collapseKey`. My question is: How can you make a notification message non-collapsible?

Note: The question applies to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) as well.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Just used a data message instead

Comment: Okay..
Also 'setBackgroundMessageHandler' is not working for v6.0+.. Any idea?
I want to get data message inside app when app is killed.

Comment: I am using data payload and having the same issue the notification updates the previous one. How to use collapse_key with data? Its not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [message concepts and options documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) states:

> messages are non-collapsible by default except for notification messages, which are **always collapsible**

But then later on the same page, it goes on to say:

> except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible **by default**

Which is somewhat ambiguous. However, in the [payload section](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload), it states:

> [notification messages] may have optional data payload. **Always collapsible**

Therefore, it doesn't seem possible to make notification messages non-collapsible.

I'd suggest that this is by design, because when creating notifications in Android, they are [automatically replaced when another notification with the same ID is posted](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Updating) (similarly to how collapsing messages works). If I remember correctly, FCM/GCM uses the same ID for all notification messages.

### Possible solution

If you do want a non-collapsible notification message, I'd suggest sending a data-only payload (with no notification or `collapseKey`), and then overriding the [`onMessageReceived()` from the `FirebaseMessagingService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived) to create your own notification.

There is an example of this available on the [Android quickstart sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/0f4c86877fc5f771cac95797dffa8bd026dd9dc7/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L47-L84):

> ```
> @Override
> public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
>     // ...
>
>     // Check if message contains a data payload.
>     if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
>
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     // ...
>
>     // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
>     // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
> }
> ```

The last comment there points you to the example [`sendNotification()` method](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/0f4c86877fc5f771cac95797dffa8bd026dd9dc7/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L113-L142).

For your scenario, you'll need to pass a unique ID to the [`notificationManager.notify()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify) call so that Android creates a new notification and does not replace any existing notifications - therefore, making the message non-collapsible.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I am using already (sending a "data" payload and processing it in the application), but I would like to know if "notification" messages can be made non-collapsible. As you say the documentation is a bit ambiguous about that.

Comment: @Grodriguez This seems to be the only viable method, and I'm under the impression from the docs that the `notification` payload is more of a simple helper service to quickly and easily send notifications, rather than the preferred method. The preferred/advanced way to use FCM is to send a `data`-only payload, perform some logic on the received message and then create your own notification if it's required. I'd wager that the 3rd quote in my answer is definitive: `notification` messages are always collapsible.

Comment: @Grodriguez Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

First off, just going to put the [FCM docs reference here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages):

> A *non-collapsible* message denotes that each individual message is delivered to the device. A non-collapsible message delivers some useful content, as opposed to a collapsible message like a content-free "ping" to the mobile app to contact the server to fetch data.

As per your question -- "*How can you make a notification message non-collapsible?*" -- have you specifying a different [`collapse_key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) for each `notification` message you send?

A collapsible message works as if each of the message has the *same* `collapse_key`. But if you specify a different one for each message, then it won't be able to replace the previous one. This would make a `notification` message *behave* like a *non-collapsible* message.

However, since you are using a `collapse_key`, it is technically still treated as a *collapsible message*. Which means it is still a subject to the limit of four collapse keys at a time:

> FCM allows a maximum of four different collapse keys per Android device to be used by the app server at any given time. In other words, the FCM server can simultaneously store four different collapsible messages per device, each with a different collapse key. If you exceed this number, FCM only keeps four collapse keys, with no guarantees about which ones are kept.

With all that said, any reason why you're not just using a `data` message payload? We use it on our app and I find it more flexible than a `notification` message.

Comment: "If you specify a different (collapse_key) for each message, then it won't be able to replace the previous one. This would make a notification message behave like a non-collapsible message." Have you actually tried this, or is it an hypothesis only?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. But it should be the expected behavior. FCM doesn't have any best practices, AFAIK. But I would strongly suggest that you just use a `data` message payload instead. If you still doubt the behavior, why not just test it out?

Comment: @AL.
Data message will work if IOS app is closed? as per my read you cant receive data messages in IOS device if app is killed is that true ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166203/ios-data-notifications-with-fcm