# FCM: Device receives only one of multiple notification messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently writing an Android app using Flutter and a Node.js backend.

On the client side, I followed the first 3 steps of the [firebase_messaging docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/index.html#android-integration) to integrate FCM into my app. The logic of my app [subscribes](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/subscribeToTopic.html) to und [unsubscribes](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/unsubscribeFromTopic.html) from several topics *(one user is subscribed to 12 topics on average)* based on different settings.

The server logic is supposed to send various notification messages based on [conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics):

```js
const firebase = require('firebase-admin')

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://<PROJECT>.firebaseio.com'
})

const title = ...
const msgList = [...]
const notifications = []
for (let msg of msgList) {
  let condition = `'${msg.topicA}' in topics && '${msg.topicB}' in topics`
  if (msg.topicX !== '') {
    condition = `${condition} && !('${msg.topicX}' in topics)`
  }
  notifications.push(buildMessage(title, msg.body, condition))
}

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return firebase.messaging().sendAll(notifications).then(resp => {
    console.log(`Sent ${resp.successCount} messages, ${resp.failureCount} failed`)
    resolve()
  })
}).then(() => {
  firebase.app().delete()
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})

function buildMessage(title, body, condition) => {
  return message = {
    notification: { title, body },
    android: {
      ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1d
      notification: {
        sound: 'default',
        vibrate_timings: [
          '0s', '0.1s',
        ]
      }
    },
    condition
  }
}
```

When I run this code, it logs `Sent 72 messages, 0 failed`. Therefore, I assume that the sending of the messages worked. The number of messages sent and the corresponding topics as well as the title change at least daily. **Based on my topic subscriptions I should actually receive about 4 push notifications on my phone. However, I only receive exactly one notification at a time.** After I had reinstalled the app and therefore subscribed to the topics again with a new token, I received all the messages I was supposed to receive. After a few days, however, it has changed back to the old behavior and I receive exactly one message every time the server sends a batch of messages.

Comment: did you try sending directly from firebase console to see if the problem is in server logic or mobile receiving the notification?
also i had a similar issue and it turns out that I was setting the same notification id in the code so the notifications gets updated not treated as a new notification check that

Comment: @Hala.M Afaik, it's not possible to send notifications based on conditions in the Console. Both sending and receiving seem to work somehow, as one message is always coming through.

Comment: @Hala.M As for the id, I'm not setting any id at all?

Comment: what i am saying is just push 4 message through the console manually and see how the app will behave so you know if the problem is in the app or in the server logic 
or even write another code to push 4 notifications without any conditions
the id when you display the notification on the phone it serves as a unique identifier I code native android so maybe the code you have is diffrent

Comment: @Hala.M I just tested it. I have reinstalled the app (hence new registration token and new subscriptions to topics) and with the same server logic I now receive all messages. I don't know exactly what the problem was, I guess it has something to do with subscription mechanism, but it doesn't seem to be the messages themselves.

Comment: @Hala.M After the weekend, the server sent a bunch of messages again today, of which I should have received four. But again I only received exactly one. I haven't changed anything in the topic subscriptions since last time...

Comment: I have the same problem. Only receive the last one i sent. Even with collapse key.

Comment: @CarlosSilva Have you checked the `collapse_key` in BigQuery? Helped finding the issue in my case.

Comment: No. Using bigQuery will i be available to see all sent or pending firebase push notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of BigQuery I found out where the problem lies: All messages have an identical `collapse_key` (the app name). Thus, if I can't receive any messages on my device at the time the server sends the messages (for example, when I'm not connected to the Internet), the messages are collapsed and I only get one message (the last message sent). This behavior seems to be intented for notification messages:

[Non-collapsible and collapsible messages (FCM Docs):](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages)

> Except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible by default.

Apparently there is no straightforward solution to this problem. FCM only supports four different `collapse_key`s at a time, so I can't just give each message a different `collapse_key`, since then I'd only get four messages at most.

I probably have to use a workaround by sending data messages and then creating the proper push notifications on the client side.

---

Related: [How to make a GCM / FCM notification-type message non-collapsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288118/how-to-make-a-gcm-fcm-notification-type-message-non-collapsible)