# Sometimes notifications are received for some users but for others dont

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Functions to let my shop customers receive a notification when a new order is placed by any user buying into their store.

I managed to do this and was working quite well, the notifications were received by the shops

```
exports.onNewOrderCreated = functions.firestore
.document('orders/{orderId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    var db = admin.firestore();

    try{
        const docData = snap.data()
        var shopId = docData.shopId;
        var userName = docData.userName;
        var total = docData.total;
 
    }catch(error){
        return handleErrorToUser(error);
    }

    var shopUserRef = db.collection('user').where('shop', '==', shopId);
    
   return shopUserRef.get().then(userDoc => {
    return userDoc.forEach(doc => {
        const deviceToken = doc.data().deviceToken
        const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "You have a new order !! ️ ",
            body: String(userName+" placed a new order for $"+total),
        }
    }
    console.log("userId:"+doc.data().displayName+" deviceToken"+deviceToken)
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload)
       });
  });
});
```

So what this functions does is, when a new order is placed under the orders collection, it will check for the shopId of that order, then it will iterate into the users collection to find the shop owner by the shopId, when the shop owner has been found I generate a notification and send it to the shop customer.

Now I think that when so many orders are beign created, this functions does not work correctly, I dont know why

Today I got a shop customer saying that the notifications were never arriving for new orders.

Is anything more than I can add to this function to make it work correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Setting the priority of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message):

You can set the priority as follows

```
android:{
      "priority":"normal"
    },
```

and the TTL:

```
"android":{
      "ttl":"4500s"
    },
```

Applied to your code should be:

```
{
  notification: {
            title: "You have a new order !! ️ ",
            body: String(userName+" placed a new order for $"+total),
        },
    android:{
      "priority":"high",
      "ttl":"4500s"
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if this case is also related to collapsed messages. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288118/how-to-make-a-gcm-fcm-notification-type-message-non-collapsible) about `collapsed`, `non-collapsed` messages, that might be of your interest. Following a summary of the answer.

According to [the message concepts and options documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages):

> Use case scenario:
>
> - Non-collapsible: Every message is important to the client app and needs to be delivered.
> - Collapsible: When there is a newer message that renders an older, related message irrelevant to the client app, FCM replaces the older message. For example: messages used to initiate a data sync from the server, or outdated notification messages.

Also:

> messages are non-collapsible by default except for notification messages, which are **always collapsible**

But then later on the same page, it goes on to say:

> except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible **by default**

Which is somewhat ambiguous. However, in the [payload section](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload), it states:

> [notification messages] may have optional data payload. **Always collapsible**

Therefore, it doesn't seem possible to make notification messages non-collapsible. I'd suggest sending a data-only payload.

There is an example of this available on the [Android quickstart sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/0f4c86877fc5f771cac95797dffa8bd026dd9dc7/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L47-L84):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        // ...
    }
    // ...
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

The last comment there points you to the example [`sendNotification()`](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/0f4c86877fc5f771cac95797dffa8bd026dd9dc7/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L113-L142) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding options because of IOS phones:

```
let options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 24*60*60 // Choose any convenient number of seconds.
}
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload, options)
```

[Check the documentation here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#defining-the-message-options)

Comment: but this is for android phones

Comment: No, it is for all FCM client SDKs