# Is it possible to send an FCM data message only for a specific platform?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So we have a use case in our apps (Android/iOS) where we need to apply some styles to our push notifications, but since our current implementation makes use of FCM notification type messages, when the Android app is in the background, the style that we applied to the notification isn't applied. Based on what we've [read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), in order for the Android app to be fully responsible for displaying and styling notifications, data-only messages are required, but we're not sure if our iOS app can handle data-only messages correctly (see [IOS data notifications with FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166203/ios-data-notifications-with-fcm)), plus we plan to add a `thread-id` so that our notifications are grouped correctly in iOS. Is it possible to have a message that looks like this:

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "android":{
         "data":{
           "type":"Chat",
           "documentcode":"PRO-0000000",
           "title":"A sent you a message",
           "body":"Hello!"
         }
      }
     "apns": {
        "notification": {
           "title":"A sent you a message",
           "body":"Hello!"
        },
        "data":{
           "type":"Chat",
           "documentcode":"PRO-0000000",
           "title":"A sent you a message",
           "body":"Hello!"
       },
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5",
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "thread-id": "PRO-0000000"
           ...
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Basically, for Android, there should be no notification and the message should essentially be data-only, whereas for iOS, the notification field is preserved, with the addition of thread-id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOS data notifications with FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166203/ios-data-notifications-with-fcm)

Comment: Hi @lazarevzubov, I did see that and got important info that data messages can't be received in iOS when the app is terminated, that's why I mentioned that we have doubts if iOS can handle data-only messages correctly. Will add that link to my question, thanks